# How to find a tag with an arbitrary attribute having an arbitrary value with Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to find `<a>` tag with `itemprop` attribute being `url`. So far the only approach i found is to use a lambda:

```
soup.find(lambda a : a.name=='a' and a.has_attr('itemprop') and a['itemprop']=='url')
```

But somehow i cannot believe that this is the best approach. Is there something simpler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a dict to find.

```py
soup.find("a", {"itemprop" : "url"})
```

Alternatively, use a CSS selector.

```py
soup.select_one("a[itemprop='url']")
```